# web3j - TypeReference for event with string parameter

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3-java

Let's say that I have the following event in my Solidity smart contract:

`event Buy(address buyer, string itemName);`

I am trying to construct the corresponding event in **web3j** Java library. This is what I have done:

```java
public static final Event BUY = new Event(
  "Buy", Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(
    new TypeReference<Address>(false) {}, // address buyer
    new TypeReference<String>(false) {}, // string itemName
  )
);
```

But, it is giving me error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Type> of the type TypeReference<T>
```

Which type should I use instead of `String`?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `String` return type with `Utf8String`. This will resolve the issue.